# How to find NULL and also Value in the same colum with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get both the nulls and value = 2
so far I tried `IN (2,null)` got only the values equals to 2
also `AND columName = 2 OR columName IS NULL`  got only values equals to 2.

```
columName
2
NULL
```

Comment: If you check the docs you'll find you compare to null as `columnName is null`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: thank you for the respond i tried this  IN (2, IS NULL) and it had syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
select * from TABLE
where field ='value' or field is null
```

I think your problem is here:

```
AND columName = 2 OR columName IS NULL
```

Should be:

```
... AND (columName = 2 OR columName IS NULL)
```

Comment: ... AND (columName = 2 OR columName IS NULL) that work thank you very much !!!

Comment: @TalDayan If it helped you, mark the answer as correct/accepted please.

Answer (score 1):

As the issue is resolved, this is just an alternate solution you may use. You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in your `Where` clause for what you are looking for. Try this :

```
select * from yourTable
where isnull(columName, 2) = 2
```

Check [SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d18e/1)